# Why does random() function in where-clause cause query to return more or less than one row?

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3

How is it possible that this query can return more than one row?  How can it return zero rows?

```
WITH cte(k,v) AS (VALUES (0,'A'), (1,'B'), (2,'C'))
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE k=round(random()*2);
```

Sometimes it returns one row, sometimes two, or three, sometimes none.  But if the `random()` function is returning one value, that value can match no more than one row in the table, right?  And if I multiply it by `2` and round to an integer, then the returned value must be either `0`, `1` or `2` and thus must match exactly one row, right?

If I put the `random()` invocation inside a subquery like this:

```
WITH cte(k,v) AS (VALUES (0,'A'), (1,'B'), (2,'C'))
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE k=(select round(random()*2));
```

then it only ever returns exactly one row, just as I would expect without the subquery.

And the query

```
SELECT round(random()*2);
```

only ever returns one row, with one column whose value is either `0`, `1`, or `2`, so I am not understanding how that can match anything but one row in the `cte` table.  Yet in the first query above, sometimes it seems to be matching more or less than one row.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, `random()` is called for *every* row in your source data and not *just once* (like you assumed).

So, every row in your source data has a 33% chance of being returned.

Answer (score 3):

As stated by others, the `random()` is called for every row.

If you want a single random row you could use an `ORDER BY random()` clause and then `LIMIT` the result to a single row, something like this (not tested):

`WITH cte(k,v) AS (VALUES (0,'A'), (1,'B'), (2,'C'))
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1;`